# Partitioned CROSS JOINs with EACH are not supported

Tags: google-bigquery

Recently I have stumbled upon the following error while executing one of my BigQuery queries.

```
Partitioned CROSS JOINs with EACH are not supported.
```

The query has been running flawlessly before, so I assume that some new limitations were introduced to BQ. Can someone give me more information on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed recent change in BigQuery, but it wasn't supposed to affect existing queries that has been working. Can you provide the actual query code which is causing this issue ?

Comment: The query is almost 200 rows.. Basically it was having "CROSS JOIN EACH" as one of the joins. I have now removed EACH and it works..

Comment: I get the same symptom in the past few days. sample job ID would be job_pckBesISCOxg9Q2rK3-z18YLVao. removing the "each" does not work for me